# Error invoking remote method 'docker-start-container': Error: (HTTP code 400) unexpected - failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed:

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

when i use docker run -d -it --restart=always --name webapp5 -v /srv/fedena:/opt/fedena/ -p 82:80 -p 3333:33 mywebapp zhs

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "zhs": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs due to a bad command being passed to one of the secondary service containers in your job.

The error message occurs due to the secondary service container crashing or exiting prematurely. This means CircleCI cannot get the PID from the Docker daemon and exits with a failure.

Error invoking remote method 'docker-start-container': Error: (HTTP code 400) unexpected - failed to create shim task

The error message "error invoking remote method 'docker-start-container': error : (http code 400) unexpected - failed to create shim task : oci runtime create failed : runc create failed: unable to start container process : error during container init: error mounting" indicates that there was an issue creating the container in Docker. There could be a variety of causes of this error, but here are a few things you can check:

Check if any of the Docker images you used to create the container have been corrupted or removed. If an image is missing or corrupted, Docker may not be able to create the container successfully. Try redownloading the images and building the container again.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).